# How to add None to the list where there is no corresponding value?

Tags: python, list, tuples, nonetype

For every element from 'b'  I need to find its value from 'a' and put it to the resulting list. If there is no corresponding value stored at 'a' I need to put None

Example:

```
getValues([("key1", "value1"), ("key2", "value2"), ("key3", "value3")], ["key2","key3","key3","key4","key1","key5"])
```

must return `["value2", "value3", "value3", None, "value1", None]`

How to fix the code so that it will add None to the list where it has to be?

```
def getValues(a, b):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
            for n in range(len(a)):
                    if b[i] == a[n][0]:
                            result.append(a[n][1])
    return result
```

Wherever I tried to put the condition about adding None it did`t work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your code, what you need to do is figure out whether you found something in `a` or not. You could `break` from the inner for loop once you find a match. That way, you can use the `for..else` syntax to figure out that you need to use `None` instead:

```
def getValues(a, b):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        for n in range(len(a)):
            if b[i] == a[n][0]:
                result.append(a[n][1])
                break
        else:
            result.append(None)
    return result
```

However, looping over `a` for every item in `b` is kind of expensive. Since `a` is essentially a look up, you should consider converting it to a dictionary. Since `a` is a list of key/value tuples, this is pretty easy; you just need to call `dict(a)`.

Afterwards, you can remove the inner loop:

```
def getValues(a, b):
    result = []
    d = dict(a)
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[i] in d:
            result.append(d[b[i]])
        else:
            result.append(None)
    return result
```

Instead of checking whether the item is in the dictionary, you can also use `dict.get()` instead which will return a default value if the key is not in the dictionary. By default this is `None` (how convenient), so you can just do this instead:

```
def getValues(a, b):
    result = []
    d = dict(a)
    for i in range(len(b)):
        result.append(d.get(b[i]))
    return result
```

Finally, instead of iterating over indexes, you should iterate over the list items of `b`:

```
def getValues(a, b):
    result = []
    d = dict(a)
    for x in b:
        result.append(d.get(x))
    return result
```

And since you append an item for every item in `b`, you could also replace this by a nice list comprehension:

```
def getValues(a, b):
    d = dict(a)
    return [d.get(x) for x in b]
```

Comment: one of my mistakes was to put  "else:result.append(None)" exactly under the if condition and now I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> [dict(a).get(el) for el in b]
['value2', 'value3', 'value3', None, 'value1', None]
```

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: `None` is the default value for `dict.get()` already.

Comment: You should consider moving the `dict(a)` outside of the list comprehension though to avoid creating a new dictionary for every item in `b`.

Comment: dictionary will be the next topic (I just started to learn how to program) so I was told to solve the problem without watching it. Is there any other way to fix the code without applying to the dictionaries?

Comment: Sure, but the code will be at least 3 times as long. Horses for courses.